# Definition of Support

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am a bit confused with the definition regarding support. Say the joint density function exists. For the random variables $X$ and $Y$, **is the joint support of $X$ and $Y$**:

the values $X$ and $Y$ can take st. $f_{X,Y}(x,y) >0$?

**Or is the support of** $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ the values $X$ and $Y$ can take st. $f_{X,Y}(x,y) >0$

In other words is it defined in terms of Random variables or probability density functions? Or are they both correct?

Comment: Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$ while $Y=X$ with probability $0.5$ and $Y=1-X$ with probability $0.5$ (implying $Y$ is also uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$).  Then neither definition is correct as they do not have a joint density.

Comment: I have adjusted the OP so it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support of random variable $X$ is a set of all values, that the random variable has. So if $S_X$ is support of $X$ and $S_Y$ is support of random variable $Y$ and they are **independent** then the support of random vector $(X,Y)$ is Cartesian product $S_X \times S_Y$.

If the vector $(X,Y)$ has density $f_{X,Y},$ the the support is set
$$S_{X,Y} = \left\{(x,y) \in S_X \times S_Y: f_{X,Y}(x,y) >0 \right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

it is defined in terms of the random variables.
AS the OP just edited , hence support is defined in terms of the random variable when joint probability density function exists.

Comment: So only the first definition is correct?

Comment: Neither is correct since you do not know, that the joint density exists.

Comment: @iiivooo Say that it exists. I have edited the OP.

Comment: I edited my answer bellow with the proper definition.